# Chrome Image Displayed Too Bright

Tags: css, image, google-chrome

I'm displaying this image on a website, however Chrome seems to be adjusting the brightness or saturation (not sure the exact term). I've only run into this problem recently, this image was displaying on Chrome correctly however some recent changes in Chrome must have changed that.

I've done a quick test with browsers and here are the results:

- Chrome Desktop (64.0.3282.186): Broken
- Chrome Mobile: Broken
- Opera: Working
- Edge: Working

Raw image can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/msTIu.jpg

Here's a side by side comparison between Chrome (left) and Edge.
[image: Side by side comparison]

Could anyone tell me the cause of this? Or perhaps point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your image is in CMYK (print) color mode. Chrome renders its colors differently.

Try to open the image with an editor (for example: Photoshop, Gimp 2), set the color mode to RGB (if the editor doesn't do that by default), and save it (or export it) with the same extension, `.jpg`. This works for me.

If your colors are changing a little bit, that is because of the conversion to RGB.